# SQL order of operations for logical operands

Tags: sql, oracle, logic, operand

I inherited some some bad SQL code (zero documentation and I'm missing the original requirements). In the where clause, it has the following:

```
A OR B AND C AND D OR E
```

From my knowledge of logical operands, my assumption is that SQL would compile this as:

```
A OR (B AND C AND D) OR E
```

Is that correct?

I have a feeling the intent was

```
(A OR B) AND C AND (D OR E)
```

and I will need to speak with those that requested this project in the first place, as I haven't seen the original requirements.

Comment: Your understanding of boolean operator precedence is exactly right: AND is stronger than OR, exactly like multiplication is vs. addition. Your guess as to the intent is probably also 100% correct (meaning that the condition is written incorrectly) but you won't know without asking those who requested the project.

Comment: If you are going to add parentheses, then the correct version would be:  `(A OR ((B AND C) AND D)) OR E`.  This is semantically equivalent to your second version.

Comment: [Documentation for condition precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80), showing that you are right as `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - No, the version you propose is not equivalent to the OP's second version. And it is impossible to know what the "correct" version is, without knowing the intent (the requirement).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. In the absence of parenthesis this should be interpreted as:

```
A OR (B AND C AND D) OR E
```